# Understanding the flow of sending stored procedure to JMS Queue

Tags: java

Suppose I have a REST end point. UI sends some parameters to this REST end point which are 
required for a stored procedure to run properly. Since this stored procedure is going to take 
a long time to run, I am planning to use JMS and put this step to JMS Queue.

Now, I am not very clear about what to put in the JMS Queue here. Usually, whatever hello world examples of JMS I've seen, they are sending a 
small message using Sender and Receiver consumes this message.

But in the case of a Stored procedure call, I am wondering what exactly should be forwarded to ApacheMQ ? If I understood correctly, 
the Sender in this case would be sending the call to the stored procedure to JMS Queue in the form of a String, and then Receiver will grab this
string message(which is a call to stored procedure) from the Queue immediately (provided I've only one item in the Queue) and Receiver will start processing it? So, by receiver processing I mean
the receiver will communicate with the database and process the query. Is this how it works basically? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short yes, the receiver has to interface with the DB to invoke the actual stored proc. From the point of calling the proc (payload to put on to the JMS queue), i would suggest pass on the bare minimum stuff to invoke the stored proc with parameters. The receiver from the JMS endpoint should know which stored proc to route to (do not expect the caller to provided it).

Comment: Thanks. By any chance, you have any documentation where I can look something related to scheduling a stored procedure or a SQL?

Comment: @john can you accept the answer if that is what you were looking for. For scheduling there are many like Quartz (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), spring has support for the same, corn scheduler if your running on Linux/Unix flavours or paid tools like auyosys.

Comment: Could you tell me what would be the flow for my asynchronous requests? I am still not very clear on this. Thanks